# Run as java application not working

Tags: java, webdriver, testng

I have some test code which uses TESTNG when I try to run as 'Java Application' I do not see anything.

I do not have a `public static void main(String[] args)` because TestNG does not prompt it.

```
import java.util.*;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Testing
{
    @Test
    public void addNotificationMessage1(){
    {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

    }
}
```

This project previously worked on my old computer but does not any-more. Also newer TestNG project I use have the same problem. Does anyone have nay ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You absolutely need a main method to run this class, consider there is no instance of this class created in a different class (even then, it would have to have a main method).

EDIT: I guess if your goal is to run the `addNotificationMessage1()` method, you could create the following main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
     addNotificationMessage1();
}
```

Comment: I think in this case, we need to declare `addNotificationMessage1();` as a `static` method.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that TestNG was not installed in my IDE.

Once I installed TesNG on my IDE, it works fine now.